# Use GPG4Win Instead of Git's Internal GPG on Windows

Tags: windows, git, gnupg

When I run `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG` within git I get no display of keys at all. On the other hand, when I run the same command in `cmd` or `PowerShell` I get an output that looks like

[image]

I also added the `gpg.program` config in the global config file by running `git config --global gpg.program "/c/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe"`. To no avail. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? As a side note, I am only using git bash and have not integrated git into windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to use `GPG4Win` in Git Bash

1. **Check if GPG4Win is in your windows path variable**

   - You can do this following this tutorial linked [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).
   - Look for a line in the `System variables` `PATH` that looks like this [image]
   - If not go ahead and add it
2. **Add `gpg.program` into git config**

   - You can do this by running `git config --global gpg.program "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe"`. This will make sure it is using the system-installed `gpg` program.

**NOTE**: If you are still having issues add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file and replace `{Your User Directory}` with your user name.

```
export GNUPGHOME="/c/Users/{Your User Directory}/AppData/Roaming/gnupg"
source ~/.bashrc # Adds the env you just added to your current session
```

That is it you should now be able to restart git bash and view all of your keys or add keys to the Windows installed `gpg` program.

Comment: What's the point of the last item on your list? This would have to be repeated every single time and without it it should work all the same if instead you provide the absolute path. It's more important to align `GNUPGHOME` with what GPG4Win is expecting.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yes, you are right everything should work without that step. I will edit my answer to remove that step.